# Customize symfony data-prototype for edit form

Tags: symfony

I know it's a common question but I cannot figure out how to achieve that.

I have a Course entity and a CourseDocument entity.

```
Course(id, documents, ...) 
CourseDocument(id, file, course)
```

In my Course form:

```
class CourseType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'course.title',
            ])            
            ->add('documents', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => MediaType::class,
                'label' => 'course.documents_list',
                'entry_options' => array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'data_class' => CourseDocument::class,
                ),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ))
        ;
    }
```

In the form I want to be able to add as many documents as I want. I set up everything, javascript included. My only issue is the data-prototype that is not what I want.

```
{% import "macros/prototype.html.twig" as prototype %}

{{ form_start(form) }}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                {{ form_label(form.documents) }}
                <div id="course_documents" class="collection_holder" data-prototype="{{ prototype.tagCollectionItem(form.documents.vars.prototype)|e }}">
                    {% for widget in form.documents %}
                        {{ prototype.tagCollectionItem(widget) }}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                <button type="button" id="add-document-btn" data-target-collection="#{{ form.documents.vars.id }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-info"><i class="la la-plus"></i> {{ 'course.buttons.add_document' | trans({}, 'labels') }}</button>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

I'm generating my prototype with a macro:

```
{% macro tagCollectionItem(item) %}
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <div id="{{ item.vars.id }}">
        <div class="custom-file">
            {{ form_widget(item.uploadedFile) }}
            {{ form_label(item.uploadedFile, item.uploadedFile.vars.label, {'label_attr': {'class': 'custom-file-label'}}) }}
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
{% endmacro %}
```

It's working pretty well except for editing. I don't want the input if I already selected a file. But I want the name of the file.

Comment: You do it by overriding the template for that specific collection field. As stated here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#fragment-naming-for-collections . You should create your own form layout file, you can do it in that same twig file or a seperate one (if you want to re-use it). And in top of your existing twig file you should point the form_theme to that file, or add it to your form themes in the framework config.

Comment: ^^ this.
I'd also like to add that you should have that link here in mind when you try form theming collection prototypes and get problems finding out the name of the formfield you have to use: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/6056

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used a macro.

```
{% macro tagCollectionItem(item) %}
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <div id="{{ item.vars.id }}">
    {% if item.uploadedFile.vars.file_url or item.uploadedFile.vars.image_url %}
        {{ form_errors(item.uploadedFile) }}
        {{ form_widget(item.uploadedFile, {'attr': {'hidden': true}}) }}
    {% else %}
        <div class="custom-file">
            {{ form_widget(item.uploadedFile) }}
            {{ form_label(item.uploadedFile, item.uploadedFile.vars.label, {'label_attr': {'class': 'custom-file-label'}}) }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    </div>
</fieldset>
{% endmacro %}
```

The twig file for the form

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
            {{ form_label(form.documents) }}
            <div id="course_documents" class="collection_holder" data-prototype="{{ prototype.tagCollectionItem(form.documents.vars.prototype)|e }}">
                {% for widget in form.documents.children %}
                    {{ prototype.tagCollectionItem(widget) }}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <button type="button" id="add-document-btn" data-target-collection="#{{ form.documents.vars.id }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-info"><i class="la la-plus"></i> {{ 'course.buttons.add_document' | trans({}, 'labels') }}</button>
        </fieldset>
```